# Error: Invalid number using pivot

Tags: oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, pivot-table, plsqldeveloper

I'm stuck with this error and I don't know how to fix it since there no line number specified. Please help me. Thank you

`ORA-01722: invalid number`

Sql script with pivot:

```
select 'Data'
||','||to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||sg1_cnt
||','||sg2_cnt
||','||sg3_cnt
||','||sg4_cnt
||','||sg5_cnt
||','||sg6_cnt
||','||sg7_cnt
||','||sg8_cnt
||','||sg9_cnt
||','||sg10_cnt
from (
select 'Data',
       to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy') dtime_day,
       trunc(c.call_date, 'IW') as ddate,
       c.dst_channel
from table1 d
left join table2 c
on c.call_date >= d.dtime_day
and c.status like 'ANSWERED%'
where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate,'IW')-12*7 and trunc(sysdate) -1
)
pivot (count(dst_channel) as cnt
for dst_channel in ('SIP/item01' as sg1,
                   'SIP/item02' as sg2,
                   'SIP/item03' as sg3,
                   'SIP/item04' as sg4,
                   'SIP/item05' as sg5,
                   'SIP/item06' as sg6,
                   'SIP/item07' as sg7,
                   'SIP/item08' as sg8,
                   'SIP/item09' as sg9,
                   'SIP/item10' as sg10))
```

Comment: Please share the table DDL

Comment: please, provide table's ddl

Comment: what do you mean ddl table?

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language - the `CREATE TABLE` statements that would create your table(s). Just at a glance, you don't seem to be giving your second column in your subquery (produced by the expression  `to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy')`) a name.

Comment: list of table's columns

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename your columns in the inner query: replace `to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy')` with `to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy') dtime_day`, else your outer query will not understand.

Comment: i got an error when I change it, here's: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: You edited your initial query, right ? But you used `ddate_day` instead of `dtime_day`, this appears strange to me as you use `dtime_day` in the outer query. Since `dtime_day` is already formatted as a char in the inner query, you can use it as is: you should replace `||','||to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy')` with `||','||dtime_day`.

Comment: i change again the ddate into dtime, the query is now running but all the results is zero? i think there's something wrong in the query. how do i display the real results and display it by weekly?

Comment: but the data has no zero result values. please help me